# How to resolve this error E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed! (android studio)

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, testing

when i try to run the app in my android device it give me this type of run-time error "E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!." How can i resolve this?

Java code

```
public class monument extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chitralmon);

        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

        if(item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home)
        {
            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```